# Default value on the new item on BindingSource Navigator

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I can't put a new default value when i click on the Plus from the Binding Navigator.
Im using vb.net, and i want to fill my TextBox with a val that i can get from a xml (a number + 1)

How can i do this?